# How to select JSON data based on UILabel value into TableViewCell in Swift 3.0?

Tags: json, swift3, xcode8, uitableview

I have this UILabel **"loginLbl"** in Swift that hold the value of **"P1111"**

```
loginLbl.text = "P1111"
```

I want to post this **loginLbl** into PHP first before my apps display the result.

The reason is in my database, I have multiple attendance data, each login have their own attendance data therefore I just want to display the record based on **loginLbl** in Swift.

So far I managed to display all "attendance" into table cell but it display all my record in database. The problem is I don't know how to filter the data before display it in apps.

**getAttendance.php**

```
<?php   
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) { 
        $login  = $_POST['login']; 
        $sql    = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$login'"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql); 
        if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
                $login_db   = $row['login']; 

                $sql2       = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE login = '$login'"; 
                $result2    = mysqli_query($connect, $sql2); 
                $attendances    = array();
                if ($result2 && mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) { 
                    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) { 
                        $timeoutdb   = $row2['timeout'];
                        $timeindb    = $row2['timein'];
                        $attendances[] = array('timeout' => $timeoutdb , 'timein' => $timeindb);
                    }  
                    $output = array('login'=>$login_db,'attendance' => $attendances);
                    echo json_encode($output);
                } 
                else {} 
            }
        mysqli_free_result($result); 
        } 
        else { echo 'record not found'; } 
    } 
?>
```

**table.swift**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginLbl: UILabel!

    var attendancestatus: [AttendanceStatus]? = []

    var login = "P1111"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchData()
        loginLbl.text = "P1111"
    }

    func fetchData() {
        let url     = URL(string: "http://localhost/getAttendance.php")
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod  = "POST"
        let valueToPost     = "login=\(login)"
        request.httpBody    = valueToPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }
            else {
                self.attendancestatus = [AttendanceStatus]()
                do
                {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]

                    let loginValue = json["login"] as AnyObject
                    if (loginValue as? String == self.numberLbl.text)
                    {
                        print("Display the table cell")
                        if let msFromJson = json["attendance"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]
                        {
                            for mFromJson in msFromJson
                            {
                                let ms = AttendanceStatus()
                                if let timeout = mFromJson["timeout"] as? String,
                                    let timein  = mFromJson["timein"] as? String
                                {
                                    ms.timeout      = timeout
                                    ms.timein       = timein
                                }
                                self.attendancestatus?.append(ms)
                            }
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableview.reloadData()
                        }
                        return
                    }
                    else {
                        print("Table cell not found")
                        return
                    }
                } 
                catch let error { print(error) }
            } 
        } 
        task.resume()    
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AttendanceCell", for: indexPath) as! AttendanceCell
        cell.timeout.text         = self.attendancestatus?[indexPath.item].timeout
        cell.timein.text          = self.attendancestatus?[indexPath.item].timein
        return cell
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.attendancestatus?.count ?? 0
    }
}
```

My json output look like this when I enter "login" value using web browser

**json**

```
{
    "login":"P1111",
    "attendance":
        [
            { "timeout":"1234","timein":"1244"},
            { "timeout":"1717","timein":"0517"}
        ]
}
```

Appreciate if someone can guide me on how to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "The problem is I don't know how to filter the data before display it in apps.", Is problem is inside your php api or is it iOS app side?

Comment: it is inside the xcode side . . right now I managed to display attendance array only . But its not possible since in my database I have many login user with their own attendance array .

Comment: What i'm trying to do is I want fetchData function post the value of loginLbl before my apps display the table cell . .  I've updated my code above . But an error occur "UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}"

Comment: But you are already passing the loginId so you will get attendance of that user.

Comment: nope . .  value cannot be display if I save the file as getAttendance.php . . error ""UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}""

Comment: Are you getting this error when you are making request to `getAttendance.php` from iOS?

Comment: yup . error occur in iOS .

Comment: Are you getting data, check that in the dataTask completionHandler.

Comment: I'm having a problem inside do statement in table.swift . let loginValue = json["login"] as AnyObject
                    if (loginValue as? String == self.numberLbl.text) . I'm not sure whether it is the correct way to declare the value

Comment: yup. I'm getting data "P1111" in dataCompletionHandler. . I'm doing like this first . .                 let loginValue = json["login"] as AnyObject
                if (loginValue as! String == self.numberLbl.text!){
                    print(loginValue)
                }

Comment: That is not JSON it is just single string.

Comment: I can print value "P1111" . But the problem occur when I start to add this code inside the if statement . "if let msFromJson = json["attendance"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
    for mFromJson in msFromJson{
        let ms = AttendanceStatus()
        if let timeout = mFromJson["timeout"] as? String,
            let timein  = mFromJson["timein"] as? String{
                ms.timeout      = timeout
                ms.timein       = timein
            }
        self.attendancestatus?.append(ms)
    }
}
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableview.reloadData()
}"

Comment: Can you just print the json nothing else, and give here the console log.

Comment: in console log . it just appear like this "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}" . I have no idea

Comment: That means from server you are not getting valid json. What is the output of this `print(String(bytes: data!, encoding: .utf8))`

Comment: on which line should I add that code ? im getting error "unresolved identifier data"

Comment: Inside the completion handler add this as first line.

Comment: I see. . . the value for "P1111" is not posted into PHP . That why the cannot run .. I change it from numberLbl.text = "P1111" into var number = "P1111"

Comment: Now it is working?

Comment: so far its working . But come new error ... When build for the first time, table cell can be load perfectly . But when I rebuild again .. "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}"

Comment: The problem is probably your PHP api is not returning proper response in all the cases

Comment: when I save JSON output as getAttendance.json , the value can be fetch into table cell . But when i save as getAttendance.php, an error "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}"  .

Comment: I have check the output . It's the same .  nothing wrong with the output . . I'm not sure why an error appear

Comment: Then call `getAttendance.json` may be your url is according to that

Comment: when create "let task" , which one is to use for data task ? is it "dataTask(with: URL)" ,  "dataTask(with: URLRequest)" ,"dataTask(with: URL, completionHandler: (data?, response?, error?) -> void)" , or "dataTask(with: URLRequest, completionHandler: (data?, response?, error?) -> void)"

Comment: still not working . . I'm not sure why when I rebuild my apps . error "no value " will appear

Comment: When I use code like this ,       let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost/getAttendance.json")!)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
            (data,response,error)in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }
        }   , table cell does not have any problem when it rebuild many times . But this code does not post any value to PHP

Comment: But when I changed it into "let url = URL(string: "")
let session = URLSession.shared
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let valueToPost = "login=\(numberLbl.text!)"
request.httpBody = valueToPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {(data, response, error)in
if error != nil {return}}" , since in my case I need to post something to PHP first to display table cell data , it won't display table cell data when I rebuild apps many times

Comment: What do you mean by "rebuild apps many times"?

Comment: I mean , restart my apps . . build and then run the current scheme

Comment: I post new question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268964/parsing-error-error-domain-nscocoaerrordomain-code-3840-no-value-userinfo

Comment: ok let me check it

Comment: Hi @NiravD , can you help me to solve this questions ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038997/uipickerview-cannot-fetch-array-output-in-swift-3-0 . I've been stuck for a days now. Thanks in advance

Comment: Let me check that