# UIPickerView cannot fetch Array output in Swift 3.0

Tags: php, ios, arrays, swift3, xcode8

I have these PHP file to fetch data from database based on **"dept"** condition.

**getDeptList.php**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['dept'])){
        $dept       = $_POST['dept'];

        $sql   = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE dept ='$dept'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

        if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                $login_db       = $row['login'];
                $real_namedb    = $row['real_name'];

                $output[]= array('login' => $login_db, 'real_name' => $real_namedb);

            }

            echo json_encode($output);
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else {
            $output = array('login' => 'wrong credentials from PHP code!');
            echo json_encode($output);
            echo mysqli_error($connect);
        }
    }
?>
```

In x code, I have value UILabel that has been set to **"ITD"** and this value need to be post into PHP first to produce Array output in UIPickerView.

Here's my code so far.

**UPDATE**

**getDeptList.swift**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var deptLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var loginLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var real_nameLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var dropdownTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var dropdown: UIPickerView!

    var persons = [Person]()

    struct Person {
        var login: String
        var real_name: String

        init?(dict: [String:Any]) {
            guard let login = dict["login"] as? String, let real_name = dict["real_name"] as? String else {
                return nil
            }
            self.login = login
            self.real_name = real_name
        }
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return self.persons.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return persons[row].real_name
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if row >= self.persons.count {
            return
        }
        self.loginLbl.text = self.persons[row].login
        self.real_nameLbl.text = self.persons[row].real_name
        self.dropdown.isHidden = true
        self.dropdownTxt.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == self.dropdownTxt {
            self.dropdown.isHidden = false
        }
    }

    func getDropdownJSON(){
        deptLbl.text = "ITD"
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost/getDeptList.php")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "dept=\(deptLbl.text!)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            if let result = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) {
                print(result)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getDropdownJSON()
    }
}
```

Console did'nt print result value

[image]

The problem is, UIPickerView can't fetch the Array output. I'm not sure why. maybe someone can help to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: self.persons = array.flatMap(Person.init) put break point in this line and check did you get data or not ?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: I'm not getting any error . . UIPickerView does not fetch the Array output

Comment: @AlotJai What is the console log for `print(array)`?

Comment: console can't print the value of array . I add print array inside if let array

Comment: @AlotJai Add this lines like this `if let result = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) { print(result) }` after than show the console log for result, Don't put this code inside the if let array block.

Comment: Still the same . . console can't print the result value . . .

Comment: The problem start in line "let task = URLSession" . . I can't print any value in the console. .

Comment: can you use url with https ?

Comment: Yup . it work with both http and https @AdrianBobrowski

Comment: @AlotJai Update your code with result one that you are trying so we will get idea what is wrong

Comment: @AlotJai Have you try this api with Postman or something else are you getting data for it? check that once

Comment: Yup . . .I tried the same way to post value to be fetch into table cell. it works fine . .  I just apply the same concept with UIPickerView but it didn't work so far . . .

Comment: Can you print a message like this `let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    print("Hello")
}` and tell me can you see this message when run the app?

Comment: @NiravD , The weird part is when i change getDeptList.php into getDeptList.json . . I can print result value using above code . . . . . I'm not sure why the value "ITD" cannot be isset($_POST). . .

Comment: @DanhHuynh , yup . i can print "hello" using your code . .

Comment: @AlotJai What is the response when you call it with the postman

Comment: Let try this code `let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    
    if let error = error {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    
    guard let data = data else {
        print("No data")
        return
    }
    
    do {
        let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
        print("result: \(result)")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}` Hopefully, it will be working!

Comment: After I recheck and retype back the code. Somehow it work . .  I have no idea . . but it works fine to me  .. .

Comment: @NiravD, response "response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60800003dc60> { URL: http://localhost/getDeptList.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 229;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Mon, 27 Mar 2017 07:15:28 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.12 PHP/7.0.12 mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/7.0.12";
} })"

Comment: @AlotJai I'm talking about JSON response

Comment: @NiravD, opps. sorry . . JSON "[   
 {"login":"001","real_name":"MIKE"},
 {"login":"002","real_name":"JOSH"}
]"

Comment: @AlotJai You have added comment **Somehow it work . . I have no idea . . but it works fine to me .** Is it working now?

Comment: yup . it's working now . thanks ..

Comment: @AlotJai Welcome mate :)

Comment: @NiravD ,  Hope you can help me on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044237/uiview-or-uiscrollview-scroll-up-and-down-when-keyboard-display-in-swift-3-0 . Thanks.

Comment: @AlotJai Let me check if possible will post suggestion

Comment: @NiravD, have you figure out the solution ?

Comment: @AlotJai I have checked your question and search on it but I don't have solution for it sorry.